# Template Files missing in wordpress theme folder

Tags: php, wordpress

Im using tyche theme for e-commerce.i have created template files for pages.like profile creating page.

Template file:
`<?php
/*
Template Name: Create Profile
*/`
when i assign this template for a wordpress page.Its working fine. but  two or three days later that template files are missing from my theme folder. What i have to do Now. Please help me.
Thanks...

Comment: create child theme and create template there it seems like your theme is get updated

Comment: Thanks Akshay Shah....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because when theme get updated all custom codes created by user, which resides in template folder, get replaced. So it is better to create a child theme and use it.

> If you modify a theme directly and it is updated, then your
>   modifications may be lost. By using a child theme you will ensure that
>   your modifications are preserved

More [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)

Comment: Happy to help . Good day :)@user8724101